# How to change background color of UISearchBar in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, background-color, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How to change background color of UISearchBar in iOS7?

[image]

not gray, I want to change color like my uinavigationbar

if I Use this code, that's what comes out

```
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

[image]

That is not red color!!!
This exact same situation as in background color of navigation bar.

Comment: is this just me or I can't see your pics?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Need to use:

```
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

[image]

All thanks!

Comment: Is that a way to remove the transparency in the searchbar ? because the color is not really red !

Comment: @AladdinGallas you simply set UISearchBar's translucent property to NO like so: `[searchbar setTranslucent:NO];`

Comment: i want to add rounded corners to this bar? how can i do that?

Comment: this does give the bar a red tone, but there is still transparency/alpha to this tone. is there a way to get rid of that and get a pure color as the tint?

Comment: Set the searchbar style to UISearchBarStyleMinimal, than you get the pure color.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't change the color for some reason. It only changed the color of the cursor? Anyone have any clues on why this happeneed?

Comment: @1290 please check if you set `searchBarStyle = .minimal`, change it to default

Answer (score 59):

Set the background image to a clear image and you're good to go. This is also pre-ios 7 compatible.

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init]
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: This is a really good answer use clearColor if you want to have a minimal design with white in the textField

Answer (score 33):

If the above solutions don't seem working then make sure that you've set the search bar style to **Minimal**.

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
```

And for simple searchBar

```
[self.searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
```

**SearchBar Style** can also be set from interface builder to **Minimal**.

Answer (score 6):

it's not really work for me , or sometimes , if you too , try this

```
for (UIView *view in [[filterTextField.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews]){
                if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UISearchBarBackground"])
                    view.alpha = 0;

            }
```

Comment: The if clause could simply be `if ([view isKindOfClass: UISearchBarBackground)`.

Comment: @franklsf95 It wouldn't work since it's an undocumented class.

Answer (score 4):

If  the UISearchBar was defined in the MainStoryBoard, just click on that UISearchBar and take a look to the options you can handle at right.
Over there if you click on the fourth tab (the one that looks like a shield) you've got a Bar Tint option. There you can select the UISearchBar color you want.

If not, I guess programatically you can do something like this:

```
    UISearchBar* sb =[[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    sb.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

I hope this helps!