# iOS 7.1 NavigationBar tintColor property bugged on iPhone 5s?

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7.1

In my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, i set my navigation bar tint color like that;

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and my all back buttons and other buttons color is white which are on navigationBar. However, on iPhone 5s device and 64-bit simulator, color become gray. Also it is gray when i launch Facebook or Twitter. Is that iOS 7.1 bug on 64-bit or am i set it wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

This was also recognized and asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316346/colour-changed-in-ios7-1-how-to-change-searchbar-colour). Basically it seems Apple has changed the tinting behavior of UISearchBar in iOS 7.1 on all devices. I can confirm that the same happens on an iPhone 5 therefore given your information this issue has nothing to do with the 64-bit processor as the iPhone 5 doesn't have such a processor. I'm experiencing this on my App as well and couldn't find any good solution yet.