# iOS 7.1 UISearchBar gray view

Tags: uisearchbar, ios7.1

I work at an application and I tested today on iOS 7.1. Until now my search bar was normal:

[image: iOS 7.0.3]

But now I have this problem:

[image: iOS 7.1]

A gray view appears and I don't know how to remove it because I don't have this view in my code.  Does anyone have the same problem? It is an iOS 7.1 bug?

Comment: Where does the view come from?

Comment: Confirmed: I am having this problem too (cept with a black background)

Answer (score 7):

My quick fix used some code I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664917/1153630

And then:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

I'm still not very impressed by it though: will update answer when I find a better way.

You may also want to checkout: [Colour changed in iOS7.1, how to change searchBar colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316346/colour-changed-in-ios7-1-how-to-change-searchbar-colour)

Comment: `[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]]` does not exists.

Comment: @JeremyC. please checkout the first link in my answer to create that method!

Comment: @Jugale - Good catch, nifty little category!

Answer (score 4):

As @dave noted above, you can just use say:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

which avoids the need for the category on UIImage incorporated in @Jugale's example.