# Searchbar Background color not applied correctly in ios7.1

Tags: uisearchbar, ios7.1

In ios7.1 UISearchbar background is Black when i set it as clearcolor. I need to get background as clearColor.

```
[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[searchBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

In 7.1, I am getting like this, [image]

But i need like this, [image]

Helpers are appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question and its answers: [iOS 7.1 UISearchBar gray view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353489/ios-7-1-uisearchbar-gray-view)

I had the same issue, and this worked for me:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```