# Two problems with UISearchBar when it is embedded in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I set a default background image for UISearchBar:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance]setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_field"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I then have a UISearchBar set to the nav bar's titleView.

```
UIView *searchView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 35)];
lsearchBar = [[TestSearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:searchView.frame];
[searchView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[searchView addSubview:lsearchBar];
```

But the result looks horrible with a crushed graphic for my search bar: [image]

If it try to embed it without using UIView directly, like this:

```
lessonsSearchBar = [[TestSearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 35)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = lessonsSearchBar;
```

it looks better, but when I push segue to the next view controller, or do pop back with animation it tries to animate it and looks horrible with this gray bar around it: [image]

I do try it inside UIView because I also want to set a custom size to my UISearchBar and realign it a bit to the left side of the screen, which for some reason is not allowed when I set my search bar directly to navitationItem.titleView. I'm not sure exactly how to achieve this without crashing my image (which I set with setSearchFieldBackgroundImage) or without those glitches with animation. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7.1 UISearchBar gray view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353489/ios-7-1-uisearchbar-gray-view)