# UISearchBar with solid color in iOS 7+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

I've tried to use all the properties `UISearchBar` has with different combinations, I've searched for the answer for a while but still can't solve the problem.

Problem:
I have a `UIViewController` with `UITableView` in it and some other view in storyboard. I've added **Search Bar and Screen Display Controller** into my project (search bar is added as a subview/header of the `UITableView`)

I need to make it red color with no transparency/translucency to match my navigation bar.

I've tried "solution" from [How to change background color of UISearchBar in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301091/how-to-change-background-color-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7) but it doesn't work. Result of this solution looks like that:

```
searchDisplayController?.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.myAppRedColor()
searchDisplayController?.searchBar.translucent = false
```

[image: First solution]

As you can see - that isn't exactly matching Navigation Bar color. It also has a separator between navbar and search bar.

Next solution almost worked:

```
searchDisplayController?.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
searchDisplayController?.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.myAppRedColor()
```

[image: Second solution, pic 1]

But when I tap on the search bar it changes color:

[image: Second solution, pic 2]

It also has very weird animation:
https://youtu.be/Dq1GKBGbmTc

Do you have an idea what else I can do instead of implementing my own SearchBar?

Comment: take a look please at my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555462/3472073

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Search Display Controller. Instead use only searchBar and TableView.
Simply delete Search Display Controller from your storyboard.
You will receive delegate methods of searchBar.
Here you can apply search on tableView.