# Change search bar scope background color

Tags: ios, objective-c

change search bar scope(all/pending) background color

Please refer below image

[image]

Comment: ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301091/how-to-change-background-color-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Answer (score -1):

I have a sample issue, and I solved this as below code.

```
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(64, 64);
UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[fillColor setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height));
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.searchController.searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = image;
```